# Javascript password validation skip if fields are empty

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

This works great, but I need it to do is also ignore it if the password field is left blank.

I want the user to be able to update their information without having to change their password. So if they leave the password fields blank, their password remain the same.

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    // JavaScript form validation

    var checkPassword = function(str)
    {
      var re = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}$/;
      return re.test(str);
    };

    var checkForm = function(e)
    {

      if(this.pwd1.value != "" && this.pwd1.value == this.pwd2.value) {
        if(!checkPassword(this.pwd1.value)) {
          alert("The password you have entered is not valid!");
          this.pwd1.focus();
          e.preventDefault();
          return;
        }
      } else {
        alert("Error: Please check that you've entered and confirmed your password!");
        this.pwd1.focus();
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
      }
    };

    var add_employee_form = document.getElementById("add_employee_form");
    add_employee_form.addEventListener("submit", checkForm, true);

    // HTML5 form validation

    var supports_input_validity = function()
    {
      var i = document.createElement("input");
      return "setCustomValidity" in i;
    }

    if(supports_input_validity()) {


      var pwd1Input = document.getElementById("field_pwd1");
      var pwd1Rule = "Password must contain at least 6 characters, including UPPER/lowercase and numbers.";
      pwd1Input.setCustomValidity(pwd1Rule);

      var pwd2Input = document.getElementById("field_pwd2");
      var pwd2Rule = "Please enter the same Password as above.";

      // input onchange event handlers


      pwd1Input.addEventListener("change", function() {
        this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? pwd1Rule : "");
        if(this.checkValidity()) {
          pwd2Input.pattern = this.value;
          pwd2Input.setCustomValidity(pwd2Rule);
        } else {
          pwd2Input.pattern = this.pattern;
          pwd2Input.setCustomValidity("");
        }
      }, false);

      pwd2Input.addEventListener("change", function() {
        this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? pwd2Rule : "");
      }, false);

    }

  }, false);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to have this at the top:

```
if(!this.pwd1.value) return;
```

javascript will return false for values of null or blank so this says return if false.

Full function:

```
var checkForm = function(e)
    {
      if(!this.pwd1.value) return;
      if(this.pwd1.value != "" && this.pwd1.value == this.pwd2.value) {
        if(!checkPassword(this.pwd1.value)) {
          alert("The password you have entered is not valid!");
          this.pwd1.focus();
          e.preventDefault();
          return;
        }
      } else {
        alert("Error: Please check that you've entered and confirmed your password!");
        this.pwd1.focus();
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
      }
    };
```

Comment: Where exactly is the "start of the function". Clearly I know next to nothing about javascript. Thank You

Comment: Thank you for that, but I'm still getting the same error message.              Error in pwd1 text.
Error in pwd2 text.

Comment: Skipped the part where i had the form input validating the data as well. required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}" -- had to remove this to get it to work. Thank You